# arm mbed os CoAP missing ns_types.h

Tags: arm, mbed, coap

I am trying to build the CoAP protocol example for ARM mbed (https://developer.mbed.org/teams/sandbox/code/coap-example/file/0681e205d0e9/) on a K64F board. I am getting this error on compiling:

```
Compile [  0.3%]: sn_coap_header_check.c
[Fatal Error] sn_coap_header_check.c@27,22: ns_types.h: No such file or directory
[ERROR] .\mbed-coap\source\sn_coap_header_check.c:27:22: fatal error: ns_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include "ns_types.h"
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

How can I obtain the missing dependency? I tried `mbed sync` and `mbed update` but I get the same error.

Any idea?

UPDATE

I am searching through the project and I can see that the file is present but not found by the compiler in this route:
mbed-os\features\FEATURE_COMMON_PAL\nanostack-libservice\mbed-client-libservice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you accidentally remove the `mbed_app.json` file? The `COMMON_PAL` feature is declared in there.

This works for me (with mbed CLI):

```
$ mbed import https://developer.mbed.org/teams/sandbox/code/coap-example/
$ cd coap-example
$ mbed compile -m K64F -t GCC_ARM
```

Comment: That works on the example. When I try to use the library on my code, that includes threading i have to mix the mbed_app.json from the coap example and the one from the threading (including some reference to uvisor). Now I get an error where the missing file is "sn_nsdl.h". What I am missing now?

Comment: I guess you already fixed it, but make sure to have `COMMON_PAL` in your features list.

Comment: Is there any reason why on this project I don't see the printf messages on the terminal?

Comment: Set your baud rate to 115,200.